# Xpages binding editable Combobox to field in document within a repeat

Tags: combobox, xpages

I have an xpage that is bound to a document (document1). The document contains two fields HW_User and HW_UserAction, both are multi-value fields. The number of values in the second field HW_UserAction will be based on the number of values in field HW_User (calculated at document creation time).

On a Xpage I would like to display the values in field HW_User in a repeat control using a computed field. For every value in field HW_User, I would also like to display a combobox with 3 values and store the selected value in field HW_UserAction in the document.
I tried multiple versions, using the combobox within the same repeat statement or in a separate one (see code below), but I just can't get the combobox (or dojo combobox) to be displayed in edit mode. Any hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Roger

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" var="rowdata" indexVar="varindex" rows="30">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValueArray("HW_User");}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowdata}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>

<xp:table>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat2" var="rowdataaction" indexVar="varindex2" rows="30" repeatControls="true">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValueArray("HW_User_Action");}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox__${varindex2}" multipleSeparator=";" defaultValue="Back to stock">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowdataaction}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Back to stock"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Transfer"></xp:selectItem>
            </xe:djComboBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>
```

Comment: If you bind field like this #{javascript:rowdataaction}, it will be always read only - there is no way to set its value back.

Comment: Hi Frantisek, thanks for your feedback. Any idea or suggestion, how I could implement what I would like to do?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/16.07.2009095816KLEBCY.htm?opendocument&comments. Make some backing beans implementing map interface with getters and setters. Then you should use expression language (EL) bindings to store combo values. Add init method to pull values from your document and save method that will put them back into fields. Call init on page open, save in querySave of your datasource.